# Database indexes - what should they be

Tags: sql, database-design, optimization

Most of my database tables have a clear unique index through which lookups are done 90% of the time but I am a bit unsure on this one - I have a table which keeps track of user rating totals for items in my database, I now want to add another table, to track individual ratings with an ip address column to make sure no one can rate something twice. Since I can see this becoming a big, high use table it is important to optimize it correctly. (MYSQL table)

This table will have the following fields:

rating_id(always - unique), item_id (always - not unique), user_id (optional - not unique), ip_address (always - not unique), rating_value(always - not unique), has_review(bool)

Now I envisions 90% the queries going something like this:

When a user rates something - select where item_id = x and ip_address = y, (if rows = 0) insert rating

When in user account pages - select where ip_address = x or username = y

Now none of the fields searched on are unique, can I still use them as indexes (for example item _id and ip_address), can I have two indexes and will this still improve performance over a non indexed table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have indexes which are unique, or not unique. 
You can have multiple indexes on a single table.
You can also have indexes on multiple fields at once.

In general, if used appropriately these will improve *querying* performance, although this may be at the expense of inserting performance.

If you want to display aggregated ratings, then you may get better performance from calculating the rating results periodically and caching the results, either in the database, or the application.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I already have a rating totals table which will be calculated either when new ratings are added or via a cron job. I also have a second table which will look up reviews by the rating_id so should I have indexes on ip_address and item_id on this table and a unique index of rating _id on the reviews table? or will I have to have rating_id as a unique index on this table for that to be effective?

Comment: I would suggest an index on (item_id, ip_address) and two further indexes on (ip_address) and (username). But this is just guesswork. Look at the query execution plan, and see how the query is being executed, then apply indexes where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of indices on each database system. In general they build a second data structure (like tree or a hash map, but I don't know the details too good to be honest) to quicken lookups.

It might therefore make sense to index your table by `username` and `ip-adress` in order to perform queries with these fields very quickly. Bear in mind that modifying the data tends to be slow, since the index must be updates as well.